# Kivy/KivyMD convert to APK - different UI on PC and device with Android

Tags: python, kivy, apk, kivymd, buildozer

I'm having trouble converting a .py script to APK.
When I run the script in PyCharm, the UI looks great. If I change the window size, everything scales nicely to the window size, but...
I use Buildozer to convert to APK and then everything seems to disappear to the lower left corner and I have no idea what it could be??
I use kivy.metrics dp,sp to make the UI scale to different devices, but no matter where I launch the APK, everything moves to the lower left corner.
The best thing is that when I click on TextFields where their graphics are, nothing works, when I click in the place on the screen where TextFields should be located, I can enter data from the keyboard. Could this be a problem with the code or converting via Buildozer? Anyone had a similar problem and have any ideas on how to solve it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.